# Python: IF filename in list

Tags: python, list, filenames

I'm trying to figure out how to go through a folder and move files that are in a list.  I have the script creating a list of file names, so now I need to be able to take the files in a folder and move them if they are in the list.

```
    import os, shutil
fileList = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'K:\Users\User1\Desktop\Python\New folder'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            fileList.append(file)
print fileList
source = "K:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\Python\\New folder"
destination = "K:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\Python\\New folder (2)"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'K:\Users\User1\Desktop\Python\New folder'):
    for file in files:
        if fname in fileList:
            shutil.move(source, destination)
```

I've used other snippets I've found online to get the list created, but I haven't been able to understand how to get the file name as a variable to check if it's in the list.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd like it to be the file name, but I don't know how to declare/define it.

Comment: you used `for file in files:` so it will be later `if file in fileList:`. You should use `for fname in files:` (`file` is a type in python, better to not use it as variable name).

Answer (score 0):

Use the right tool for the job:

```
from glob import glob
import shutil
import os

# source = "K:/Users/User1/Desktop/Python/New folder"
# destination = "K:/Users/User1/Desktop/Python/New folder (2)"
source = "."
destination = "dest"

txt_files = glob(os.path.join(source, "*.txt"))
print txt_files

for fname in txt_files:
    if not os.path.isfile(fname):
        continue
    print "moving '{f}' to '{d}'".format(f=fname, d=destination)
    shutil.move(fname, destination)
```

And you make your life easier if you don't use backslashes in paths. Python can handle this Windows weirdness pretty well...

*EDIT*
Here is version that works recursively:

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch

# source = "K:/Users/User1/Desktop/Python/New folder"
# destination = "K:/Users/User1/Desktop/Python/New folder (2)"
source = "."
destination = "dest"

for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(source):
    for fname in fnmatch.filter(files, "*.txt"):
        src_path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        des_path = os.path.join(destination, fname)
        if os.path.exists(des_path):
            print "there was a name collision!"
            # handle it
        print "moving '{f}' to '{d}'".format(
            f=src_path, d=destination)
        shutil.move(fname, destination)
```

Comment: WHile I agree that `glob` is a better tool for matching with regular expressions, it does not allow to traverse subdirectories like `os.walk` does.

Comment: there is a `fnmatch` then :) see other version.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to move all text files that are in one folder to another folder? Or do you want to pass the name of a file on the command line and if its name is in fileList, then move it to that folder?

In the former case, you can reduce your code to:

```
import os, shutil

source = r"K:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\Python\\New folder"
destination = r"K:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\Python\\New folder (2)"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root,file), destination)
```

That will move all textfiles found in the source directory to the destination directory. There is no need to keep an intermediate list then.

If however you wanted the second case, so using a commandline string passed as an argument, then you could filter it by changing the last 2 lines of the code above to:

```
if file == sys.argv[1]:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(root,file), destination)
```

Remember to `import sys` then. `sys.argv` is an array that contains the commandline parameters that were used when you called the python script. Element 0 is simply the name of the script, element 1 the first parameter which you could then use as a variable in your script.

Comment: If I understand how the script works, I'd like to run a loop on "New Folder" that looks at each file name and if the file name is in "fileList" then it moves the file to "New Folder (2).  That's what my goal is.  The comments so far have been helpful, thank you.

Comment: @user3646005, but that's what the code does. The way you construct `fileList` is by checking all files in "New Folder" and if it happens to be a text file, you add it to the `fileList`. Then, in your 2nd loop you try (but fail, because the code is incorrect) to move all the files in fileList into the 2nd folder. But rather than doing that, you could immediately move that file elsewhere the first time you detect that it is a text file. If this is not what you want, you might want to update your question to better reflect what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have an answer, but can't enter it since I'm a new user.  I have to wait 8 hours.  :-/  Thanks, Oliver.  My Python skills are pretty basic, so I try to do things in sections.  Then once things are working I see if I can condense it.  :-)